# prove that a function is differentiable if its sum is differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Prove that $f(x)$ is differentiable $iff$ $U(x) = x^2 + f(x)$ is differentiable for all $x$

Here's my proof please let me know if it's OK:

$x^2$ is differentiable for all $x$ because it's a polynomial. Thus if $f(x)$ is differentiable for all $x$ then $U(x)$ is differentiable for all $x$. Let $U(x)$ be differentiable for all $x$. Thus according to addition arithmetic $U(x) - x^2$ is differentiable for all $x$.

But $U(x) - x^2= x^2 + f(x) - x^2 = f(x)$. Thus the addition that differentiable itself equals $f(x)$ therefore $f(x)$ is differentiable as well.

I have to admit that there was a very similar exercise in my class and from which I used the "addition arithmetic" however I'm not sure what it would refer to. Does this refer to the fact that according to derivatives arithmetic the result of addition of 2 function which are differentiable themselves is differentiable? But we didn't actually derive these functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are indeed allowed to use the fact that the sum of differentiable functions is again differentiable and that polynomials are differentiable as well, then your work is fine.

$U(x)$ is the sum of two differentiable functions, hence differentiable. And if $U(x)$ is differentiable, then so is $U(x) + (-x^2) = f(x)$.

Comment: When you're saying "if I'm indeed allowed to use the fact" do you mean that it's not really a theorem? I mean is it something universal or specific to my class?

Comment: It _is_ a theorem, but it would be strange to use it if it wasn't covered and/or mentioned in your class or course notes yet. So if you have seen the theorem and you're allowed to use it in this exercise, then it's fine.